# Create a masked UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to do something that I thought would be possible, but have no idea how to start.

I have created a UIView and would like it to be filled with colour, but in the shape defined by an image mask. i.e. I have a PNG with alpha, and I would like the UIView I have created to be UIColor.blue in the shape of that PNG.

To show just how stupid I am, here is the absolute rubbish I have attempted so far - trying to generate just a simple square doesn't even work for me, hence it's all commented out.

```
let rocketColourList: [UIColor] = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.purple, UIColor.orange]
    var rocketColourNum: Int = 0
    var rocketAngleNum: Int = 0
    var rocketAngle: Double {
        return Double(rocketAngleNum) * Double.pi / 4
    }
   var rocketColour = UIColor.black
    public func drawRocket (){
        rocketColour.set()
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("rocketMask"))
        addSubview(imageView)
        //maskimage.frame = self.frame
        //let someRect = CGRect (x: 1, y: 1, width: 1000, height: 1000)
        //let someRect = CGRect (self.frame)
        //let fillPath = UIBezierPath(rect:someRect)
        //fillPath.fill()
        //setNeedsDisplay()

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do any masking, just set the rendering mode of the image to always template and set the tint color of the image view.

Comment: No idea how to do any of that, but thanks

Comment: Please try to keep your post on-topic and avoid telling us how you feel about the problem.  It would also help if you tell us what this code IS doing instead of what it's NOT doing.

Answer (score 1):

Set image as template, then set tint color for UIImageView. Something like that:

```
guard let let image = UIImage(named: "rocketMask")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) else { return }
imageView.image = image
imageView.tintColor = .blue
```

Also you can do that through the images assets:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but that all comes back with red dots next to it. Cannot assign to property: 'renderingMode' is a get-only...

Getting slightly sick of red dots at the moment

Comment: @Idiot sry, answer fixed